# Verify that a method is called - Unit Test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to code some Unit tests in java for an android app, but as I am a newbie in Unit Test implementations, I think I need some help for the following specific problem.

I have tried to find solutions on google and inside stackoverflow but I didn't find any answer that helped me.

I have this very simple method inside the **class A** :

```
@Override
    public void beeperChanged(boolean active) {
        b.setBeeper(active);
        savePrinterToData(b);
    }
```

**b** here is an instance from **class b**.

**savePrinterToData** is a method that allows to save in the database the instance **b**

I want to test this methods, more specifically test if, when I call **beeperChanged**, then **setBeeper** is called on **b** and if **savePrinterToData** is also called.

I have written this :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({PosApplication.class, AppInfoHelper.class, SharedPreferencesHelper.class})
public class OnePrinterSettingFragmentPresenterTest {


    @Mock
    private A mA;

    @Mock
    private B mB;

     @Test
        public void beeperChanged() throws Exception {
            boolean boo;
            boo = true;
            mA.beeperChanged(boo);
            verify(mB).setBeeper(boo);
        }
```

I have read that **verify** can more or less do this task of checking if a method is called. But android Studio underlines in red the statement saying that it is wrong, and does not gives me any solution.
(I am currently not testing if **savePrinterToData** is called, because I want at least to solve the issue with **setBeeper** first)

I am quite stuck, any help would be very nice. 
Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a mock implementation of the methods you wish to verify that are being called? The mock implementation will be a standard unit test assertion, which if not reached - would indicate that the methods are not being called.

Comment: Did you write a static import for the `verify` method?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have imported **import static org.junit.Assert.**

Comment: I'm delighted to hear it.  Have you imported the `verify` method?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem sorry a mistake happened when I copy-paste : I have imported import static org.junit.Assert.* this was suggested by android studio when I typed the verify method Edit : mistake again this is the right import suggested by android studio ^^ import static org.easymock.EasyMock.verify;

Comment: So you're using PowerMock with EasyMock?  Or some other combination of frameworks?

Comment: Android Studio has only imported PowerMock and EasyMock. Do you think it can be the source of the problem ?

Comment: Well, you seem to be using the Mockito syntax, not the EasyMock syntax.  So either use Mockito, and write Mockito code; or use EasyMock and write EasyMock code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how you are using Powermock.
Normally, @Mock should be used for the dependencies of the class under test
And the instance of the class under test should be obtained with @InjectMocks annotation.

```
@InjectMocks
private A mA;

@Mock
private B mB;
```

The difference: @Mock creates a "dumb" proxy of the class while @InjectMocks creates a real instance of the class and tries to match and set the @Mock instances with that class's fields.
So in the code you showed, mA is a dumb proxy test object which beeperChanged method is not being called

Update
Sorry didnt read it was easymock framework, and my answer was assuming mockito. For Easymock I think the equivalent annotation is @TestSubject